# How to remove class when I have one item as slick-slidee

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I have page where I have slides from slick. I want to achieve that when there is one item in gallery that I remove class of bgImage in it. I tried to do it with onInit func but it's not working. Is there maybe some simple way to achieve it?

```
    $('.js-sliderGallery2').slick({
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        speed: 500,
        cssEase: 'ease',
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1200,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    slidesToScroll: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 567,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 479,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    centerMode: $('.js-sliderGallery2 .item').length > 1, //this is where I want to remove bgImage class, when it's false
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 360,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    centerMode: false,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

and this is html

```
<div class="gallerySlider">
<div class="slider js-sliderGallery2 slick-initialized slick-slider">

<div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable"><div class="slick-track" role="listbox" style="opacity: 1; width: 343px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="item col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 slick-slide slick-current slick-active" style="width: 343px;" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00">
<a class="inner" href="#zoomModalProductsGallery30592" title="" data-index="0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#zoomModalProductsGallery30592" tabindex="0">
<div class="img bgImage">
<img src="" alt="">
</div>
<span class="playIcon"></span>
</a>
</div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

So basically I want to do that only between 479 and 360 screen width.

Comment: You could do this with a resize event listener. But it's most likely way easier to change/reset the styles for this class by a media query like so : `@media (min-width:360px) and (max-width:479px){.bgImage{background:none}}`